ffmpeg - set language to mapped stream (audio and subtitle)
I use some software for live streams/channels, it has option/field to put ffmpeg commands. When i have stream with multiple audio and subtitles streams and i want only few select, i use this option (example): -map i:0x04B1 -map i:0x04B2 -map i:0x04DF  -map i:0x04E0 In this example it mapped video (first stream), audio (second stream) and two subtitles (third and fourth stream).
And its okay. But when i play stream (output) players (like VLC) show subtitles as Unknown or just DVB subtitles. I mean, it works but does not show language of subtitle or audio.
In original stream, i mean input, it normally shows language of every subtitle and audio. Its probably software's fault.
Can i add something to ffmpeg command, not only to map stream but also add language info to mapped stream?
Thank you in advance
I tried some solutions. | I need to convert decimal numbers of streams to hexadecimal for ffmpeg command to work.
